# What javascript tree data structures are available?

Tags: javascript, tree

Are there good libraries for manipulating trees in javascript? Just to be clear, I am looking for tree as in data structure not display model.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here are some libraries that you may find helpful:

[arboreal.js](https://github.com/afiore/arboreal), a "micro-library for traversing and manipulating tree-like data structures" in node.js and the browser.

[buckets](https://github.com/mauriciosantos/buckets/), a "complete, fully tested and documented data structure library" that includes BSTs, a heap, and a bunch of other goodies.

Comment: Too bad arboreal doesn't seem to maintained anymore, 3 pull requests waiting for 2 years now. buckets looks real good but appart from bst it does not really provide tree data structures

Comment: TreeModel as indicated by @JNS seems to be the best option.

Comment: On a project I worked on for the Rwandan NGO Solid Africa, tree structure was a important part of keeping track of expenses and donations (your expense or donation belonged to a category, food, special care etc.). Based on this experience I developed the [tree-util node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-util). I hope it can be helpfull when you want to work with tree structures. Especially if you relate data to your tree structures.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136016/965921 for a custom solution,

Answer (score 32):

Two libraries to add to the list are:

- [t.js](https://github.com/aaronj1335/t-js) - Seems to be good for traversal;
- [TreeModel](http://jnuno.com/tree-model-js/) - Manipulation and traversal.

*disclaimer: I built TreeModel*

Comment: Awesome library, actively maintained, will use it!

Answer (score 8):

Try the DOM

```
var o = document.createElement( 'WHAT_YOU_WANT' )
// o.appendChild( ... )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide a good answer. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: I do not disagree with this answer. The DOM is a tree strucure, compatible with XML and JSON. Removing nodes, adding children, children containing children. Add a little CSS and you can easily a good looking treeview structure. Furthermore the question does not specify the widget appearance they want.

Comment: This is a good answer, why is this downvoted?

Comment: not all trees live in the browser, though it would be nice to be able to use a tried and tested implementation.

Comment: Not a good answer, it is not a generic tree structure and relies on a specific implementation with specific side effects.

Comment: I don't think DOM can be considered as a JavaScript data structure. But I upvoted this answer since I like those who think outside the box.

Answer (score 5):

Wish I'd seen that solution before, because those libraries look helpful!

Here is one I put together which is an alternative.  Meant for traversal, manipulation and loading of hierarchical tree structures from self referencing flat tables, not for balanced binary trees.

[DataStructures.Tree](https://github.com/stephen-james/DataStructures.Tree) and [related blog post](http://stephenjamescode.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/building-tree-in-javascript-to-convert.html)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what your needs are so this is a shot in the dark.
I normally use (for lightweight Javascript) an array of arrays, like this:

```
node[i] = [parent, firstChild, secondChild, ... nthChild];
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one simple data oriented tree library called [data-tree](https://github.com/cchandurkar/Data-Tree). You can use this to create, traverse and search tree in BFS/DFS fashion. You can also import/export data from tree.  Checkout the detailed documentation at: http://cchandurkar.github.io/Data-Tree/

To use it in a node `npm install data-tree`

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Comment: @Kyll, thanks for bringing it to my attention. I don't want to reinforce any such belief. Would it be appropriate if I delete my answer?