# Javascript: Building a hierarchical tree

Tags: javascript

My data has these properties:

1. Each entry has a unique id (Id)
2. Each has a Parent field, which points to the Id of the parent.
3. A node can have multiple children, but only one parent.

My first attempt to build a tree is below. It is buggy as the recursion causes an infinite loop. Even if I solve it, I am not sure if there is a better approach to do this. Currently, I am doing it in 2 passes.

I would like it to be as efficient as possible as I have a decent amount of data. It also needs to rebuild the tree dynamically (the root can be any node)

There is sample data in the program below:

```
 arry = [{"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""}, {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"},
    {"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},{"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"}]//for testing
```

I was hoping the output to be (it might be wrong nested structure, as I manually wrote it. but, what I am hoping is a valid JSON structure with node as a field 'value' and children as an array.)

```
{
 "value": {"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""},
 "children": [
  {
   "value": {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"},
   "children": [
    {
     "value": {"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},
     "children": []
     },
     {
     "value": {"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},
     "children": []
     }
   ]
..
}
```

Sample program:

```
function convertToHierarchy(arry, root) 
{
//root can be treated a special case, as the id is known
    arry = [{"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""}, {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"},
    {"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},{"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"}]//for testing


    var mapping = {}; // parent : [children]
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        var node = arry[i];

    if (!mapping[node.Id]) { 
          mapping[node.Id] = {value: node, children:[] } ;
        }else{
      mapping[node.Id] = {value: node} //children is already set    
    }

    if (!mapping[node.Parent]) { //TODO what if parent doesn't exist.
                mapping[node.Parent] =  {value: undefined, children:[ {value: node,children:[]} ]};
        }else {//parent is already in the list
        mapping[node.Parent].children.push({value: node,children:[]} )
    }

    }
    //by now we will have an index with all nodes and their children.

    //Now, recursively add children for root element.

    var root = mapping[1]  //hardcoded for testing, but a function argument
    recurse(root, root, mapping)
    console.log(root)

    //json dump
}

function recurse(root, node, mapping)
{
    var nodeChildren = mapping[node.value.Id].children;
    root.children.push({value:node.value, children:nodeChildren})
   for (var i = 0; i < nodeChildren.length; i++) {
        recurse(root, nodeChildren[i], mapping);
    }
    return root;
}
```

I have 3 good solutions so far, and hope the upvotes suggest more idiomatic, efficient implementation. I am not sure, utilizing the property of my data that, there will be only one root element in the set of input array, and also the root is always given, any of these implementation could be better. I should also be learning how to benchmark, as my requirement is how efficiently (fast/without much memory) the tree can be rebuild. For example, the input is already cached (array) and rebuild the tree like

```
convertToHierarchy(parentid)
....
convertToHierarchy(parentid2)
...
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
var items = [
    {"Id": "1", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"},
    {"Id": "2", "Name": "abc", "Parent": ""},
    {"Id": "3", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "5"},
    {"Id": "4", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"},
    {"Id": "5", "Name": "abc", "Parent": ""},
    {"Id": "6", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"},
    {"Id": "7", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "6"},
    {"Id": "8", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "6"}
];

function buildHierarchy(arry) {

    var roots = [], children = {};

    // find the top level nodes and hash the children based on parent
    for (var i = 0, len = arry.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = arry[i],
            p = item.Parent,
            target = !p ? roots : (children[p] || (children[p] = []));

        target.push({ value: item });
    }

    // function to recursively build the tree
    var findChildren = function(parent) {
        if (children[parent.value.Id]) {
            parent.children = children[parent.value.Id];
            for (var i = 0, len = parent.children.length; i < len; ++i) {
                findChildren(parent.children[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    // enumerate through to handle the case where there are multiple roots
    for (var i = 0, len = roots.length; i < len; ++i) {
        findChildren(roots[i]);
    }

    return roots;
}

console.log(buildHierarchy(items));​
```

Comment: Thank you for a neat working solution. I will wait for votes to see what others think about more efficient sol. In my case root is given (say, rebuild the tree at this parent). Would that necessarily affect the sol. Thanks again for the succinct sol.

Comment: 5 years later, still saved my life !

Comment: Worked perfectly. I was able to convert it to Java for my use. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone guide if i want to update this heirarchy tree after inserting a new node.

Answer (score 8):

**While the above solutions do work** - I think they are **very slow** and unoptimised with too many loops and outdate methods (we will use **ES6** syntax). I recommend using the bellow optimised solution which will give you a performance boost. [Read this blog post to understand how this works.](https://medium.com/@Kivylius/building-a-hierarchical-tree-from-a-list-explained-in-detail-4c4ed60d1f1c)

`javascript`

```js
const hierarchy = (data) => {
    const tree = [];
    const childOf = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
        const { Id, Parent } = item;
        childOf[Id] = childOf[Id] || [];
        item.children = childOf[Id];
        Parent ? (childOf[Parent] = childOf[Parent] || []).push(item) : tree.push(item);
    });
    return tree;
};

// print
console.log(hierarchy([{"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""}, {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"}, {"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},{"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"}], { idKey: 'Id', parentKey: 'Parent' }));
```

Here some results and comparisons between other posters

[image]

http://jsben.ch/ekTls

---

If you looking for version with parameters for a **more dynamic but slightly slower version** here it is bellow:

```
const hierarchy = (data = [], { idKey = 'id', parentKey = 'parentId', childrenKey = 'children' } = {}) => {
    const tree = [];
    const childrenOf = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
        const { [idKey]: id, [parentKey]: parentId = 0 } = item;
        childrenOf[id] = childrenOf[id] || [];
        item[childrenKey] = childrenOf[id];
        parentId ? (childrenOf[parentId] = childrenOf[parentId] || []).push(item) : tree.push(item);
    });
    return tree;
}
```

Happy hacking

Answer (score 7):

Here's another one. This should work for multiple root nodes:

```
function convertToHierarchy() { 

    var arry = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "" }, 
    { "Id": "2", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "1" },
    { "Id": "3", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2" },
    { "Id": "4", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"}];

    var nodeObjects = createStructure(arry);

    for (var i = nodeObjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currentNode = nodeObjects[i];

        //Skip over root node.
        if (currentNode.value.Parent == "") {
            continue;
        }

        var parent = getParent(currentNode, nodeObjects);

        if (parent == null) {
            continue;
        }

        parent.children.push(currentNode);
        nodeObjects.splice(i, 1);
    }

    //What remains in nodeObjects will be the root nodes.
    return nodeObjects;
}

function createStructure(nodes) {
    var objects = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        objects.push({ value: nodes[i], children: [] });
    }

    return objects;
}

function getParent(child, nodes) {
    var parent = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].value.Id == child.value.Parent) {
            return nodes[i];
        }
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Comment: You have a couple of bugs.  First, your `convertToHierarchy()` function doesn't actually return anything, you just need to add a return statement for `roots`.  Also, the check `currentNode.value.Id == ""` doesn't do anything since none of the `Id`s are empty. Otherwise works nicely :)

Comment: Thanks, Bill, good spotting. The incorrect `currentNode.value.Id == ""` has been changed to instead check for the Parent. I admit, that part of the code was added without even running it ;)

Comment: +1. I will evaluate with others. My data is guaranteed to be rooted at single node. Does that change the sol. My consideration is how fast, with least memory the tree can rebuild if I specify the root.

Comment: A single root node will be fine.

Comment: this only works if the nodes are correctly ordered, if the order is random it will give incorrect results

Answer (score 3):

I'd have done something like this. It handles multiple root nodes and is fairly readable IMO.

```
array = [{"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""}, 
    {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"},
    {"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},
    {"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},
    {"Id":"5", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""},
    {"Id":"6", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"5"}];


function buildHierarchy(source)
{

    Array.prototype.insertChildAtId = function (strId, objChild)
    {
        // Beware, here there be recursion
        found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length ; i++)
        {
            if (this[i].value.Id == strId)
            {
                // Insert children
                this[i].children.push(objChild);
                return true;
            }
            else if (this[i].children)
            {
                // Has children, recurse!
                found = this[i].children.insertChildAtId(strId, objChild);
                if (found) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    // Build the array according to requirements (object in value key, always has children array)
    var target = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
        target.push ({ "value": source[i], "children": []});

    i = 0;
    while (target.length>i)
    {
        if (target[i].value.Parent)
        {
            // Call recursion to search for parent id
            target.insertChildAtId(target[i].value.Parent, target[i]); 
            // Remove node from array (it's already been inserted at the proper place)
            target.splice(i, 1); 
        }
        else
        {
            // Just skip over root nodes, they're no fun
            i++; 
        }
    }
    return target;
}

console.log(buildHierarchy(array));
```

Comment: Tanks Jan. Same as comment above. Will for for votes/comments to see how others compare. Thanks again.

Comment: If speed is the biggest issue, use huge input data and do a benchmark test. If readability and mantainability is your biggest issue, choose the code that makes the the most sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented in ES6, with a simple sample input. Can test in the browser console

```
let array = [{ id: 'a', children: ['b', 'c'] }, { id: 'b', children: [] }, { id: 'c', children: ['b', 'd'] }, { id: 'd', children: ['b'] }],
  tree = (data) => {
      let nodes = Object.create(null),
          result = {};
      data.forEach((item) => {
        if (!nodes[item.id]) {
          nodes[item.id] = {id: item.id, children: []}
          result = nodes
        }
        item.children.forEach((child) => {
          nodes[child] = {id: child, children: []}
          nodes[item.id].children.push(nodes[child])
        })
      })
      return result
    }

console.log(tree(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

guys what if I am using it inside nodejs and need to created nested ul/li instead of json? can please write the code