# make a tree form [{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6}]}]

Tags: javascript

i have a string variable  in javascript like this:

```
var tree='[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children"[{"id":6}]}]';
now i want to create a tree from this in which
# 1 and 2 will at same level
# 3 ,4 ,5 will be the sub nodes of 2.
# 6 will be the sub node of 5.
```

Please help to make a tree form  this tree variable by javascript or jquery.
 variable.

Comment: can you be more specific? a `tree` is a `data structure` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640823/what-javascript-tree-data-structures-are-available . what exactly do you need?

Comment: do you want to make tree from tree !

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to it, in my opinion. I found some typos, but otherwise, it is a JSON structure. There was a colon missing after the second "children" and some closing brackets were missing too. And i removed the quotes.

```
var tree = [{
      "id" : 1
    }, {
      "id" : 2,
      "children" : [{
          "id" : 3
        }, {
          "id" : 4
        }, {
          "id" : 5,
          "children" : [{ //missing colon
              "id" : 6
            } //missing bracket
          ] //missing bracket
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tree[0]));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tree[1]));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tree[1].children));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tree='[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children"[{"id":6}]}]';
var objTree = JSON.parse(tree);

console.log(objTree);
```

Just a heads up that you have a couple of typos - to find them, take your string and just plop it into the parser at http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

There's a few typo, see the comment for that.
Anyway, you just have to convert using `JSON.parse`

```
var tree='[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6}]}]}]'; 
//Missing ':' near 'children' and '}]' at the end

var array = JSON.parse(tree);
```