# i want to split a string to get values in loop

Tags: javascript

I want to split below string:

```
var tree = [{
  "id" : 1
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "children" : [{
      "id" : 3
    }, {
      "id" : 4
    }, {
      "id" : 5,
      "children" : [{ 
          "id" : 6
        }
      ] 
    }
  ]
}];
```

I want to split this string to get the values:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6.
```

Now how can i split it to get values.

Comment: That's no string.

Comment: Do you really have that code as a string???

Comment: Try `myString.match(/\d+/g)` or `myString.split(/\D+/)`

Comment: Do you ever try things by yourself? You just posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408730/make-a-tree-form-id1-id2-childrenid3-id4-id5-childr) to get your `tree` on an array, without even trying out before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there looks like `JSON`

Try this:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + tree + ')');

var ids = findIds(myObject);

// this is untested, but the principle applies
function findIds(o) {

    var ids = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {

        ids.push(o[i].id);
        ids.push(findIds(o[i].children));
    }

    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a javascript object its probably faster to traverse the tree and collect the ids.
If this is a string you can eval to get a tree object.

```
function collect(tree,arr){
  for(var i=0;i<tree.length;i++){
     arr.push(tree[i].id)
     for(var j=0;j<tree[i].children;j++){
        collect(tree[i].children[j],arr)
    }
 }
}
```

To call the function

```
var arr=[];
collect(tree,arr);//arr will have results
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if this really is a string would be to use a regex (you could use this approach in the future if your string isn't code that can be eval'ed).

```
var ids = str.match(/\d+/g);
```

would return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

(assuming that whole string is in a var called 'str').

Answer (score 0):

I always get yelled at for not providing 'vanilla javascript' answers, but so be it.  It seems like what you want is [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit):

```
var tree = [{   "id" : 1 }, {   "id" : 2,   "children" : [{
      "id" : 3
    }, {
      "id" : 4
    }, {
      "id" : 5,
      "children" : [{ 
          "id" : 6
        }
      ] 
    }   ] }];

jsel.match(tree, '.id');
```

You could also do this with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) but you'd need to flatten it and it would be much less elegant.