# Need an algorithm to convert string to JSON with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, loops, recursion

I'm calling an api for the history of an ID which returns a string object that looks like this:

> 09304790130000--09304790090000
>   09304790130000--09304790120000
>   09304790090000--09304790010000
>   09304790120000--09304790020000
>   09304790120000--09304790030000
>   09304790120000--09304790110000
>   09304790110000--09304790050000
>   09304790010000--042322003
>   09304790020000--042322002
>   09304790030000--042322001
>   09304790050000--042322004

I could do so much more with it if I could figure out how to use JavaScript to convert it to JSON so it would look like this:

```
{
    "name": "09304790130000",
    "children": [{
        "name": "09304790090000",
        "children": [{
            "name": "09304790010000",
            "children": [{
                "name": "04 2322-003"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "09304790120000",
        "children": [{
            "name": "09304790020000",
            "children": [{
                "name": "04 2322-002"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "09304790030000",
            "children": [{
                "name": "04 2322-001"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "09304790110000",
            "children": [{
                "name": "09304790050000",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "04 2322-004"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Is there an algorithm I can use that can construct the object I need regardless of how complicated the "tree" becomes?

EDIT for clarity:
The "--" in the string represents the relationship of the ID's.  The left ID is the parent of the ID right of the dashes. So the ID that I feed the api, "09304790130000" has two children, each could have more children until they reach the current 9-digit ID.

Comment: In ECMAScript, "string object" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @amphetamachine: Actually, no -- JavaScript (ECMAScript) has both string primitives and string objects.

Comment: So is each line a child of the previous line? Is there only ever one code per line?

Comment: Are you sending it somewhere else? JSON is just a markup format for strings. I think what you really want is to convert the string you get into a JavaScript object or array (which could then be easily returned as JSON if you are sending it further along)?

Comment: And where does `04 2322-003` come from? You need to explain how the mapping is supposed to work (and in the process, you might just answer your own question).

Comment: @user3038802 I intend to use the JSON format to display the data with the d3 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is an input that is in a custom format. What you need to handle it is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). (Although your format might be simple enough that a full on regex function is not required so much as splitting on separators?) You need to do is break the input string up and loop over the components and put those into your desired data structure (which sounds like it would be some kind of tree). The high level pseudo-code would be something like:

```
Take line of input.
Break on "--".
Create root node from the left side if the tree is empty, otherwise just find the existing node.
Add child from right side to the parent.
```

Getting it into the JSON format you want may require also writing a function that iterates over the tree and writes a string in that format... although if you are using existing libraries and data types this probably already exists.

EDIT: To expand on the last bit, to get the format you want would mean a [Pre-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) of the tree. At each step you just add the formatting and name to the JSON String. [One of these libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640823/what-javascript-tree-data-structures-are-available) should have the capabilities you need, although obviously you can write a tree data structure and traversal function yourself if you need to.

Comment: I appreciate your input, especially where others often dispute the semantics but it's the iteration loop that's got me hung up.